# Как получить активный маршут в Angular?

Tags: angular-routing, angular

В JavaScript можно получить текущую ссылку вот таким образом: `window.location.href`.
А как можно в Angular получить ссылку на текущую активную страницу?

Бывают например `utm` метки, которые не должны попасть в строку, поэтому не подходит способ встроенный в JavaScript.

Comment: У класса Router есть `url`, возвращает url текущей страницы - вам не подходит?

Comment: @Василиса не знал

Comment: Можете ответ дать? Кодом

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У класса Router есть url, возвращает url текущей страницы:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
    template: 'The href is: {{href}}'
    /*
    Other component settings
    */
})
export class Component {
    public href: string = "";

    constructor(private router: Router) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.href = this.router.url;
        console.log(this.router.url);
    }
}
```